# Is a complex continous function of $f$ on a disk around the origen also continous as a function of $\bar{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, leibniz-integral-rule

I am trying to use the Leibnitz theorem on a continous funktion $f: B \rightarrow \mathds{C}$, with $B$ being an open disk around the origen of Radius $R$, on $f$ as a function $f(z, \bar{z})$.
It is given that $f$ is continous on $B$.
According to my textbook I can use the Leibnitz theorem on this function.
For this to be true, that would mean that $f$ also has to be continous as a function of $\bar{z}$. Why would that be the case?

Comment: What is the Leibniz theorem?

Comment: I meant the Leibniz integral rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $z\longmapsto f\big(\overline{z}\big)$ it as a composition of
$$
z\longmapsto \overline{z}
$$
and
$$
z \longmapsto f(z)
$$
And use the fact that a composition of continuous functions is a continuous function.